# Explanation for Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock Ruby Solution

Tags: ruby

So I need help understanding the solution to the leetcode problem:

```
Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

If you were only permitted to complete at most one transaction (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the stock), design an algorithm to find the maximum profit.

Note that you cannot sell a stock before you buy one.
```

The following solution:

```
def max_profit(prices)
  if prices.size < 2
    return 0
  else
    profit = 0
    min_price = prices[0]  # set to 2

    (1..prices.count-1).each do |k| # number of days
      profit = prices[k] - min_price if profit < prices[k] - min_price #profit = 4 - 2 if 2 < 4 - 2
      min_price = prices[k] if prices[k] < min_price #4 if 4 < 2
      # if 7 < 0 
    end
    return profit
  end
end
```

I have trouble understanding the else section. If we go over this step by step,
We start off with defining the initial values. We have the initial value for the profit set to 0 since we aren't making any profit by default. The next step is what I am not so sure about:

1. Why are we setting the minimum price to prices[0]? I thought we could have used the min method to find the minimum value of the array but it doesn't give the desired output.

Now, I have no idea what the rest of the statement is doing. It just seems like we are iterating through the days, starting from day 1 which is something that I don't understand in the first place.

Would anyone give out a full, simple explanation of how this solution works?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `prices.combination(2).max_by{|buy, sell| sell - buy }` is an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this question is:

> you were only permitted to complete at most **one** transaction

So in other words, the task is:

> Given a list of prices, find the biggest chronological gap between lowest--> highest price

For example, given the following input:

```
[5, 11, 6, 2, 5, 3, 10, 1, 4]
```

Then the optimal solution is to buy when the price is `2`, then sell when it's `10`. (Even though the price does reach `1` and `11`, there is no way to make a bigger profit from one transaction!)

So now, let's look at the code.

The first part is just a guard clause:

```
if prices.size < 2
  return 0
```

"If there's only one price, then it's impossible to make a profit. Return `0`."

The rest of the algorithm then works as follows:

1. Set the *"minimum price up until today"* as `min_price`. (Because if you *sell* at any point the future, then this must have been the optimum time to *buy*.)
2. Step through each day. The profit you'd make if you sold on that day is: `prices[k] - min_price`. If this is a "new record", then store the value as an updated `profit`.
3. Check whether this is a new record lowest price to buy (`prices[k] < min_price`). If so, then update `min_price` to this day's price.

Let's use the above input as an example:

```
[5, 11, 6, 2, 5, 3, 10, 1, 4]

# Day 1: min_price=5, profit=0
# Day 2: min_price=5, profit=6 (Buy at 5 [day 1], sell at 11 [day 2]) -- New Record
# Day 3: min_price=5, profit=6 (Buy at 5 [day 1], sell at 11 [day 2])
# Day 4: min_price=2, profit=6 (Buy at 5 [day 1], sell at 11 [day 2])
# Day 5: min_price=2, profit=6 (Buy at 5 [day 1], sell at 11 [day 2])
# Day 6: min_price=2, profit=6 (Buy at 5 [day 1], sell at 11 [day 2])
# Day 7: min_price=2, profit=8 (Buy at 2 [day 4], sell at 10 [day 7]) -- New Record
# Day 8: min_price=1, profit=8 (Buy at 2 [day 4], sell at 10 [day 7])
# Day 9: min_price=1, profit=8 (Buy at 2 [day 4], sell at 10 [day 7])

# Final result: profit = 8
```

---

If you were allowed to make multiple transactions, then the algorithm would look very different. (You should buy whenever the price is about to up, and sell whenever it's about to go down.) Perhaps you could give this a go, too.